# Why does resizing in kivy brings back widgets in old positions?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a game in kivy and when I close the screen (android) or try to resize the window (linux) some widgets that I've moved away from the screen return to their starting position.
I created a minimal reproducible example for that:

## example.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class GameCanvas(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def start(self):
        # move the label widget far away
        self.children[0].pos = 10000, 10000

class Example(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

## example.kv

```
GameCanvas:

<GameCanvas>:
    Button:
        text: 'Start Game'
        size: root.width, root.height / 2
        on_release: root.start()

    Label:
        text: 'Game Title'
        size: root.width, root.height / 2
```

Before pressing the button:
[image]

After pressing the button:
[image]

After resizing:
[image]

As the attached images show after I press the button the label 'disappears' (moves position) but when I try to resize the Window it comes back.

Why does this happen? Also why does it happen on android as well? Does it have to do with some sort of events in kivy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is the intended behavior of the `BoxLayout`. The `BoxLayout` positions its children. So, you can move the `Label`, but as soon as the `BoxLayout` gets a chance (as in a size change event), it positions its children as intended. If you want to control the position of the children widgets, then you should use a `Layout` that does not position its children, perhaps a `FloatLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thanks! RelativeLayout indeed doesn't let that happen